# How do import statements modify a module's symbol table?

Tags: python

I have the following module:

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   random.py
```

`random.py` is just an empty file, and `__init__.py` contains this:

```py
import random

def print_random():
    import foo.random
    print(random.random())
```

When I call the above function with `python -c 'import foo; foo.print_random()'`, I'm getting `AttributeError: module 'foo.random' has no attribute 'random'`.

It appears that the import statement in `print_random()` has replaced the reference to the built-in module with the reference to `foo.random`. Can anyone explain to me why it has not added a new record in the aforementioned table? Where can I read more about it? And is there a recommended practice for avoiding this situation?

**Update #1**

I am getting the same error with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. The only difference I have noticed is that with Python 2 the wording is slightly different: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random'`.

`sys.modules['random']` in `print_random()` is referring to the built-in random module, but `globals()['random']` is referring to `foo/random.py`.

`import foo.random` does not have to be in `print_random()`. It can be removed from there and added to the command used to run the script (e.g. python -c 'import foo; import foo.random; foo.print_random()'), and that will produce the same result.

Comment: This might not be relevant, but what version of Python are you using?

Comment: No, `import random` is importing the first `random.py` it finds which happens to be yours. `import foo.random` is not affecting the behavior of your code in any way.

Comment: Per the doc you linked to, "This mapping [sys.modules] serves as a cache of all modules *that have been previously imported*, including the intermediate paths" (emphasis added). Why would you expect it to contain the built-in random?

Comment: As for the recommended practice: do not name a module the same as another module if you do not have the explicit intention of shadowing it. (Cannot find a link that says so, but it seems to be common sense).

Comment: Weird, I get a `KeyError` with the same command from a fresh interpreter on Python 2.7 (version probably irrelevant though). What do you get when making that print statement within your `print_random()` function? Maybe edit your post with that additional information?

Comment: This is a special case related to `__init__` files, writing a longer answer now.

Comment: @Leporello apologies re my previous comments - I was checking `sys.modules` in iPython, and `random` is included. But you're right, at the command line you get a `KeyError`. However, it's clear from the error message that the issue is with `import foo.random` mapping to `random` and the `import random` line is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mechanisms at play here:

On the one hand, when executing the `import foo.random` statement, we would normally expect that the name `foo` will be bound in the local context, and `foo.random` will be available as a member of `foo` per the import statement's [docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

On the other hand, "when a submodule is loaded using any mechanism [...] a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object" per the submodules [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules).

In the special case of an `__init__.py` file this means that `foo.random` will be available both as the name `random` and as the `random` member of the object bound to `foo` since in the `__init__.py` file we are working directly in the parent module's context (ie. we are working in the `foo` context, not in the `foo.__init__` context).

The best solution is to not to write code in the `__init__` package if it can be avoided and just use it to expose names, initialize loggers etc. It's also good practice to always create a package for modules that are to be exposed relative to the parent package  for expressiveness, although it doesn't solve this problem.

In conclusion, if you wanted to expose a `foo.random` package while having a `foo.print_random` function with the above content, I'd suggest the following layout:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  print_random.py
  random/
    __init__.py
```

foo/__init__.py

```
from foo.print_random import print_random
```

foo/print_random.py

```
import random

def print_random():
    import foo.random
    print(random.random())
```

Comment: Added more detailed file layout example